Selecting the right index in a field attribute passed from python to geonode network
I have a geonode network that instanciates 3D bars on a grid. I want to put a number on top of the bars, a different one for each. These numbers come from a csv file. I extract them and pass them as named attributes to the geonodes network. All that works well.
Problem comes now. I can put the integers as text on top of the bars, it works, but I get the same number on top of all the bars. In reality I need the right number that belongs to each bar. The named attribute is a field, it contains all the numbers for all the bars. I need to somehow extract the right value from that field that corresponds to the index of the bar that is being addressed at each moment. How can I do that? I have tried all sorts of fields related nodes and sample index node etc but nothing works

Use something like Attribute Viewer or Index Viewer or use a repeat zone to iterate over all bars and for each add a single string curve.

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/, with the csv data already imported as named attribute ? Are numbers integers or floats ?
